# Uploading files to FTP Server

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ftp, c#-3.0, sftp

Im trying to ulploade files to and ftp Server, but when i run the method it uploades only 2 files and then stalls. It stalls on this line

```
Stream uploadStream = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();
```

When i reach this line the first 2 times, the program checks my certificate and then continues, but the third time it stalls and never goes on checking my certificates.

here is the full code:

```
public void UploadLocalFiles(string folderName)
        {
            try
            {

                string localPath = @"\\localFolder\" + folderName;
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(localPath);
                string path;            

                foreach (string filepath in files)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
                    reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://serverIP/inbox/"+fileName));
                    reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
                    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                    reqFTP.EnableSsl = true;
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Certificate;
                    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(localPath +@"\"+ fileName);
                    FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();

                    int bufferLength = 2048;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];

                    Stream uploadStream = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();
                    int contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

                    while (contentLength != 0)
                    {
                        uploadStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                        contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in GetLocalFileList method!!!!!" + e.Message);
            }

        }
```

As i saied, when i reach the uloadStream code it checks my certificats, here is my certificate method

```
 public bool Certificate(Object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
        {
            { return cert.Issuer == "myCertificate"; }
        }
```

Is there some way to only connect to ftp server once, and do the certificate once and hold the session?? cuz right each time i want to uploade or download a file i connect and verify the certificate for each file..

Comment: that's probably not the cause of your problem but you should always close streams after use (in a finally block maybe?): uploadStream.Close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably hitting the default connection limit for [ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.connectionlimit.aspx), which is `2`. The [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8exfzxft.aspx) has a [`ServicePoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.servicepoint.aspx) property that you can adjust. You will need to close your `uploadStream` as soon as the upload is finished.

Comment: when adding this before my catch line, the files do not get uploaded, when i remove them only the 2 files get uploaded.      uploadStream.Close(); fileStream.Close();

Comment: Im setting the ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = files.Length,  and it works. But i dont know if that is best practice.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line in entry point of your app:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

Comment: Yes. I have similar situation while consume web service. So, basically if there is a need to accept certificate this will do...